# Obtaining the standard deviation from a pair of (truncated) normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

The expectation value of one side truncated (upper tail) normal distribution is defined as follows:

$$
 \operatorname{E}(X \mid X>a) = \mu +\sigma\lambda(\alpha) \!$$
where 
$$
\alpha=(a-\mu)/\sigma,\; \lambda(\alpha)=\phi(\alpha)/[1-\Phi(\alpha)],
$$

$$
\phi(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2\right)},
$$
and $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cumulative normal distribution function.

My question:

Given $\operatorname{E}(X \mid X>a)$, $\mu$, and $a$, how do I obtain $\sigma$ using an analytic formula (non-iterative)?

Comment: You are looking for an analytic formula, not a numerical method?

Comment: Is $\sigma$ given with $\mu$

Comment: Yes I am looking for an analytic formula. An iterative approach I have already.

Comment: No $\sigma$ needs to be obtained from E(X∣X>a), μ, and a.